# Cant understand this anonymous function syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anonymous-methods, angular-meteor

The following code:

```
  angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', function ($scope) 
  {
    $scope.helpers({
          parties: () => {
            return Parties.find({});
          }
    });
  });
```

demo at [Angular Meteor Tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding)

Can't understand the syntax used for `parties:` object. Why is `=>` used ? Is there more explanation for this kind of anonymous function.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this looks like an arrow function.

Comment: thanks new to arrow function syntax

Answer (score 4):

This is an arrow function, new syntax from [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015) standard which was accepted this year. Not only arrow functions are shorter in declaration and sometimes looks nicer, they also share binding context with their surrounding code

```
!function() {
  this.name = 'global';

  var nonArrowFunc = function() {
    console.log(this.name); // undefined, because this is bind to nonArrowFunc
  }

  var arrowFunc = () => {
    console.log(this.name); // this taken from outer scope
  }


}();
```

You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [here](http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html) and [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this)

Comment: is it compatible with latest smartphones and cordova html viewer

Comment: @aj_blk not sure, however you can always use babel compiler to transform your new amazing ES2015 JS code to old good ES5 JS